# float right making text looks smaller

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this html :

```css
.CONNECT-WITH-US {
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color: #141b2f;
        padding: 5px 24px 0 24px;
    }
    
    .connect {
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="CONNECT-WITH-US"><label>CONNECT WITH US</label><label class="connect">CONNECT WITH US</label></div>
```

This code look like this in small screens(mobile)
The second label in the div getting smaller text.
Is that because of the float?

[image]

Comment: Consider posting your code and describing your issue correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Isn't it `font-size : 8px` that's causing your issue ?

Comment: can you please explain what is getting smaller

Comment: No, that is the size for whole div(both the labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some editing in the code

works on mobile screens.
maybe I couldn't understand what you want to ask ...

```css
.CONNECT-WITH-US {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #141b2f;
    padding: 5px 24px 0 24px;
}



.CONNECT-WITH-US .label-2 {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="CONNECT-WITH-US">
<label>CONNECT WITH US</label>
<label class="label-2">CONNECT WITH US</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The font size is for both the label, that's why I added the style on div. problem is the first label having 8px size but the second label looks smaller.

Comment: There are so many errors in this CSS. How is this the accepted answer? And with two upvotes?

Comment: @Turnip correct and that much CSS isn't even needed

Answer (score 0):

```css
.CONNECT-WITH-US {
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color: #141b2f;
        padding: 5px 24px 0 24px;
    }
    
    .connect {
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="CONNECT-WITH-US"><label>CONNECT WITH US</label><label class="connect">CONNECT WITH US</label></div>
```

For some reason the `font-size` seems to make one piece of text smaller on your screen. Even in the snippet the thing worked fine. It seems like if you are on a phone then the `float: right` doesn't play well and makes one piece of text the original `<p>` size and the other is the `8 pixels` you declared. If you're really committed to having it be that size on a phone, you could try some sort of `@media` CSS to make the style different on a smaller screen.